# Getting multiple celebrations falling on same date - sql server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I have an employee data source in sql server from which I need to retrieve the list of employees whose either of the criteria below falls on the current day

1. Their Joining date
2. Their Wedding date
3. Their Birth date

Each employee record has the above information. Based on these conditions, I need to concat a string in the query like

- If Employee 'A' celebrates birthday today, I need to display 'Happy Birthday A'
- If Employee 'B' celebrates anniversary today, I need to display 'Happy Anniversary B'

I am newbie to writing sql queries & I have tried this.

```
select CONCAT(given_name,' ',sur_name) as name,
      photo_link,birth_date,join_date,wedding_date 
  FROM emp_db where (DATEPART(dd,birth_date) = DATEPART(dd,getdate())
                 OR DATEPART(dd,join_date) = DATEPART(dd,getdate()) 
                 OR DATEPART(dd,wedding_date) = DATEPART(dd,getdate())) 
                AND status = 'employed' 
  ORDER BY Day(birth_date), Day(join_date), Day(wedding_date)"
```

Can someone please suggest a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a UNION. That is slightly different from what you are asking, as it will provide multiple record for the same employee, if and only if, they celebrate more than one event in the same day. Something like this:

```
(
  SELECT *, birth_date AS celebration_date, CONCAT('Happy birthday, ',given_name,' ',sur_name) AS celebration_message,
  FROM emp_db WHERE DATEPART(dd,birth_date) = DATEPART(dd,getdate()) AND DATEPART(mm,birth_date) = DATEPART(mm,getdate())
) UNION (
  SELECT *, wedding_date AS celebration_date, CONCAT('Happy anniversary, ',given_name,' ',sur_name) AS celebration_message,
  FROM emp_db WHERE DATEPART(dd,wedding_date) = DATEPART(dd,getdate()) AND DATEPART(mm,wedding_date) = DATEPART(mm,getdate())
) UNION (
  SELECT *, join_date AS celebration_date, CONCAT('Happy work anniversary, ',given_name,' ',sur_name) AS celebration_message,
  FROM emp_db WHERE DATEPART(dd,join_date) = DATEPART(dd,getdate()) AND DATEPART(mm,join_date) = DATEPART(mm,getdate())
)
```

Comment: DatePart gives only a part of date. so say someone having birthday on 11th of november will get happy birthday on 11 april also

Comment: Thanks. I corrected it... but who knows? Maybe he does want to celebrate monthly with his employees :)

Comment: @Frazz I would love to celebrate monthly with my employees if I own a company :)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
select case  
when 
   ( convert(varchar(10),ondate,103) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103 ) and  CelebrateType='Birthday' ) 
   then  ('Happy Bithday '+ UserName ) 

   when ( convert(varchar(10),ondate,103) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103 ) and  CelebrateType='Anniversary ' ) 
   then  ('Happy Aniversary '+ UserName ) 

    when ( convert(varchar(10),ondate,103) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103 ) and  CelebrateType='Joining' ) 
   then  ('Happy joining '+ UserName )    
 end  as Congretecolumnn

 from TableName  
 where convert(varchar(10),ondate,103)= convert(varchar(10),getdate(),103)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return the correct records, however you won't know which condition was true.
i.e. You don't know if they're in your result because it's their birthday, or because it's their anniversary...,

You can either check each result date to see which ones were a 'hit', Or you can have your query do it.

I think you want to use dayofyear, rather than day in the month that will be returned by datepart('dd'), I think you can also use datepart('dy')

```
SELECT CONCAT(given_name,' ',sur_name) AS name, photo_link,
  IF ( DAYOFYEAR(birth_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate()),'Birthday',NULL) AS birthday
  IF ( DAYOFYEAR(join_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate()),'Joined',NULL) AS joined,
  IF (  DAYOFYEAR(wedding_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate()), 'Wedding', NULL) AS wedding, 
  FROM emp_db WHERE ( DAYOFYEAR(birth_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate())
             OR ( DAYOFYEAR(join_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate()) 
             OR ( DAYOFYEAR(wedding_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate()) 
            AND (status = 'employed') 
  ORDER BY Day(birth_date), Day(join_date), Day(wedding_date)
```

The usual thing is then to loop through your query result and display each row as appropriate.

Also consider the case where an employee can have joined/married/been born on the same date.

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
     if ($row['birthday'])  $txt .= 'Happy Birthday, '.$row['name']."\n";
     if ($row['joined'])  $txt .= 'Happy Work Anniversary, '.$row['name']."\n";
     if ($row['wedding'])  $txt .= 'Happy Wedding Anniversary, '.$row['name']."\n";
 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Loopo. Could you explain what this line does IF ( DAYOFYEAR(birth_date) =  DAYOFYEAR(getdate()),'Birthday',NULL)

Comment: DAYOFYEAR will give you problems... in leap years all the days from march on to december have a different DAYOFYEAR than in non-leap years. As an aside, you should not use getdate()... unless you want to bash on those unlucky few that would like to celebrate feb 29th for some reason or another.